# whem i am trying to call JavaScript method in html if methods parameter is null my result is method's caller scripts

Tags: javascript, html

i have html code to get and print string from JS method

```
 <div class="commentDiv">{{ commentSubString(item.commentList[0].content) }} </div>
```

here is my JS method

```
$scope.commentSubString = function(fullComment)
    {
        var subString;
        if(fullComment.length<16 && ullComment.length>0)
            {
                subString=fullComment;
            }
        if(fullComment.length<=0 || !fullComment)
        {
            subString="";
        }
        if(fullComment.length>=16)
        {
            subString = fullComment.substring(0,15);
        }
        return subString;
    }
```

if methods argument is not null the result is correct, but if it is not initialized the result is  methods caller script

```
{{ commentSubString(item.commentList[0].content) }}
```

like in this picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4oOW.png)

Comment: Maybe you got an error and render not work properly. Try to use `typeof fullComment != 'undefined'` in your processing function'

Comment: @PavloZhukov When `'use strict'` is on, `!fullComment` would indicate that it is null / undefined or empty string

Comment: @Icepickle But this check done after first check, where author can get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this:

```
<div class="commentDiv">{{ commentSubString(item) }} </div>
```

and:

```
 $scope.commentSubString = function(item) {
    if(!item || !item.commentList[0] || !item.commentList[0].content){
        return "";
    }
    var fullComment = item.commentList[0].content;
        if(fullComment.length>=16) {
            fullComment = fullComment.substring(0,15);
        }
    return fullComment;
}
```

Comment: i changed it like this{ $scope.commentSubString = function(item) {
  if(!item || !item.commentList[0]){
   return "Empty";
  }
  var subString="Empty";
  var fullComment = item.commentList[0].content;
  if (typeof fullComment != 'undefined' || ullComment.length<=0){
   subString="Empty";
  }else {
   if(fullComment.length<16) {
    subString=fullComment;
   }else {
    subString = fullComment.substring(0,15);
   }
  }

  return subString;
 } }and i have everywhere Empty result

Comment: i fixed it. try it again.

Comment: @Gog1nA How come this isn't the accepted answer? From the comments I read it as this one helped, but the one from PavloZhukov not

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `fullComment` is not `undefined` before processing it:

```
$scope.commentSubString = function(fullComment) {
    var subString;
    if (typeof fullComment != 'undefined' || fullComment.length<=0)
        subString="";
    } else {
        if(fullComment.length<16) {
            subString=fullComment;
        } else {
            subString = fullComment.substring(0,15);
        }
    }

    return subString;
}
```

You've and error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` in your version of code.

Comment: @Gog1nA Maybe property `commentList[0]` is not defined before calling function?

Comment: @Gog1nA Try to check `typeof item.commentList[0] != undefined` before read `content` property

Comment: typeof fullComment != 'undefined' >> typeof fullComment == 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that your second `if` statement does not work;

delete second `if` and initialize subString - `var subString = "";`

also you can check `fullComment` for `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Start the function as this 
$scope.commentSubString = function(fullComment='')